# How to compose multiple $(document).ready() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a function which creates dynamic `<select>`. I have to make it a multiple select options, so I have to initialise it as well.

The function is called multiple times; here's the function:

```
function renderTimezoneFilterStringCriteria($filterKey,$onChange,$r,$c,$for)
    {

        echo '<script>
                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $("#zoneFilter_criteria_'.$for.'_'.$r.'_'.$c.'").multiselect({
                    includeSelectAllOption: true,
                    enableFiltering: true,
                    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
                    maxHeight: 150
                 });
                });
                </script>'.'<div class="time_zone_list"><select name="rules['.$r.']['.$c.']['.$for.'_timezone]" class="input_field zonefield" id="zoneFilter_criteria_'.$for.'_'.$r.'_'.$c.'"  style="width:30%; margin-right:5px; float:left;">';
        foreach ($this->timezoneArrayNotDefault as $k => $val) {
            $selected = '';

             $val_array = explode(")",$val);
            if (isset($val_array[1]) && trim($val_array[1]) == trim($filterKey)) {
               echo $selected = SELECTED;
            }

            echo '<option value="' . $val . '"' . $selected . '>' . $val . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select></div>';
    }
```

Now, as you can see, the html is made as php string (my client stated that by this way, the html loads faster so he used this technique, and U can't convince him to alter to another way.

Now let's come to the point: if the function is called multiple times, then it's also causing multiple $(document).ready(function(){});

Is there any way, that I can have only `$(document).ready(){});` and initialise the multiple drop-downs in some other way??

Comment: Try just rebinding the jquery when you added more html. So when you page appends new html you call a rebind function that would rebind the jquery to the current html.

Comment: how?? can u suffest a snippet of code?? @mattfetz

Comment: no, actualy i mispelled it over there, my original code is fine

Comment: I put an answer with an example I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag variable.

```
$firstCall = TRUE;
renderTimezoneFilterStringCriteria($filterKey,$onChange,$r,$c,$for, &$firstCall);
```

And check it:

```
function renderTimezoneFilterStringCriteria($filterKey,$onChange,$r,$c,$for, &$firstCall)
    {
        if($firstCall) {
            echo '<script> $(doucment).ready(function() { ... '; 
            //your document.ready here
            $firstCall = FALSE;
        }
    // your other stuff here
    }
```

UPD: The better solution probably is to make single function wich echoes your document.ready, and call it once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of just rebinding your code when you add the new html.

http://jsfiddle.net/64e41LL9/

Html

```
<div id="container">
   <button class="button-item">I am a button</button>
</div>
<br/>
<button id="add-html" >add button</button>
<br/>
<button id="rebind" >rebind</button>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //function to rebind
    function rebind() {
        $('.button-item').click(function(){
           alert("Im binded");
        })             
    }

    //initial bind on page load
    rebind()

    //adding new html thats unbinded
    $("#add-html").click(function(){
         $("#container").append('<button class="button-item">I am a button</button>')
    })

    //calls function to bind new html 
    $("#rebind").click(function(){
        rebind()
    })

})
```

So essential what is happening here is when the page loads you will initially bind the alert code to the button but when you append new html to the page you will see the new button won't fire the on click event even though it has the same class. This is because its not binded. Once you click that rebind button it will rebind all the buttons with that class(button-item). You can use the same concept but it will call the rebind function everytime you add your dynamic html.